# MySQL query to Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE age = 10 AND (first_name like %name% OR last_name like %name%);
```

How do you do this in Laravel 5.5?

Comment: You can do it anywhere using the `DB` module, the most common choice is in a `Model` for the entities in table. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models

Answer (score 0):

Using query builder:

```
$results = DB::table('table')
    ->where('age', 10)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query
            ->where('first_name', 'like', '%name%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%name%');
    })
    ->get();
```

Check the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) (5.5) for Query Builder

Comment: I actually did this but when I searched for first names with age of 10 it shows the results but if I search for last names with the age of 10 it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to query

```
$data= DB::table('table')
            ->whereRaw('age'= ? AND (first_name like ? OR last_name like ?)', [10,'%'.name.'%','%'.name.'%' ])
            ->get();'
```

Official documentation  to select  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many field do you use in your view.. but if you have firstname field and lastname field, then your code should be like this:

```
$results = DB::table('table')
->where('age', 10)
->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query
        ->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->first_name .'%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->last_name .'%');
})
->get();
```